# Why would the animatronics in 'Five Nights at Freddy's 4" want to harm a child?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

The animatronics in [Five Nights at Freddy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Nights_at_Freddy%27s) may be the spirits of deceased but in FNAF 4, why would they want to harm an innocent child *UNLESS* he is somehow related to the original night guard?

Comment: possibly better suited for Arqade? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Skooba - It's a 'plot' question which means it's well on topic here.

Comment: I've not played it, but [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Nights_at_Freddy%27s_4) on wikipedia would seem to indicate that when he's attacked it's actually in a dream sequence...

Comment: @Richard is "survival horror" on-topic though? I am not seeing this as a SFF game...

Comment: @Skooba The animatronics are either scifi (if they're just advanced robots) or fantasy (if they're possessed or something), so it should be on-topic.

Comment: @RogueJedi So that would mean Chuck E. Cheese is a SciFi restaurant because it has animatronics? Just not seeing it. I'm going to meta! LOL

Comment: @Skooba No, the animatronics in FNaF are obviously much more advanced than our own, especially since IIRC, some of the games take place in the 70's.

Comment: The real problem here is that this series is notorious for not having any clear answers, even by Word of God, so any answer will be primarily opinion based and extremely speculative.

Comment: @RogueJedi the struggle is real!!!  Or at least there is inconsistancey in which questions are closed as off-tpoic...  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/does-fantasy-include-the-supernatural-what-about-horror

Comment: Having worked at Chuck E Cheese's, I can tell you that things that defy nature and logic absolutely take place there.

Comment: @RogueJedi If my question about the fallout universe's space program is on topic, then surely this is.